# Code coverage not shown in Sonar when using spring agent + Jacoco + Maven surefire plugin

Tags: maven

When we are using Jacoco + spring agent + maven surefire plugin.. Junit Code coverage statistics is not shown and also the classes which should get instrumented through spring agent are not getting instrumented.

```
<plugin>
<groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
  <forkMode>once</forkMode>
  <argLine>
    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-agent/${spring.version}/spring-agent-${spring.version}.jar -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.6.1/aspectjweaver-1.6.1.jar
  </argLine>
  <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

our unit test cases are running but Junit code coverage report is not shown in Sonar cube.
When we remove spring agent and run again then Junit code coverage report is getting generated.
so we are not sure where we are going wrong and how to solve this issue.
we even tried setting forcount=1 but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show whole pom but I guest that you use:
jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent somewhere.

jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent set argLine property internaly, so when you configure argLine for surefire you simply overwrite it.

One solution is described on page:
http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html

Another way you can try this solution:

```
<properties>
   <argLine/> <!-- empty for preventing syntax error in pom -->
</properties>
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <argLine>${argLine} ... custom config</argline>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```